# Expect language - using spawn to send a variable

Tags: tcl, expect

Trying to automate a task moving hundreds of files with different formats and names

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set times 1
set a1 "First_file.txt"
```

I was trying

```
spawn mv a$times /tmp/a$times
```

Just brings #spawn mv a1 /tmp/a1

I need to get:

```
spawn mv First_file.txt /tmp/First_file.txt
```

Also using

```
spawn mv ${a{$times}} /tmp/${a{$times}}
```

gives me error: cant read "a$times": no such variable

Comment: It's Tcl syntax error. Expect uses Tcl. You need to learn Tcl (see [tcl doc](https://www.tcl.tk/doc/) ) to use Expect. You can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) if you are more familiar with shell syntax.

Comment: based on your posted code you don't need to use Expect. a simple shell script would do the job.

Comment: Or a non-expect Tcl script.

Comment: (the normal thing in tcl would be to use a dict or array or list to hold the file names, not try to build a variable name and dereference it (though that *is* possible, don't do it)

Comment: I simplified the example, this is not exactly what I will do it. But it shows in a simple way something that I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

A more natural way to achieve this in Expect/Tcl would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

foreach filename {
    First_file.txt
    Second_file.txt
    Third_file.txt
    ....
} { file rename $filename /tmp }
```

See https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/foreach.htm and
https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M30

Comment: Does `file rename` work across filesystem boundaries (Like `/tmp` is likely to have)?

Comment: Yes this does work across filesystem boundaries.

Comment: Nice. Stuff like that is often just a thin wrapper over the `rename(2)` syscall, which typically doesn't allow it.

Comment: just tried with `strace`, for `file rename /a/file/on/nfs /tmp`, it'll first try `rename()` which fails with `EXDEV (Invalid cross-device link)`, then it'll create the dst file on its own.